# Blender 'HECL' Ripping program causing animation data to be lost in UE4 on import

Tags: blender, unreal-engine4, fbx, ripping

I recently managed to rip 3D models out of Retro's 2002 Metroid Prime from its Gamecube ISO using a program called HECL ([download page](https://github.com/AxioDL/urde)). The program extracts all kinds of files from the game and puts them into Blender's .BLEND format.

My Goal is to get the models and animations into UE4 using FBX format, however when importing into UE4, only one bone from the armature shows up and all animation data is lost.

This is a problem I've heard about from other people as well, however no one has a solution. My only theory is that the issue is in some part due to an added 'HECL' tab in these .BLEND files that is irremovable. Keep in mind that I have little experience in Blender, and almost no experience in UE4, however I have been able to export/import my own meshes and animation successfully.

Blender export settings:

Version: FBX 7.4 binary

Main:
Selected Objects: Checked
Scale: 1.00
Apply Scale: All Local
Forward: -Z Forward
Up: Y Up

Armature and Mesh are selected

!EXPERIMENTAL! Apply Transform: Unchecked
Custom Properties: Unchecked
Path Mode: Auto
Batch Mode: Off

Germetries:
Apply Modifiers: Checked
Use Modifiers Render Settings: Checked
Smoothing: Face
Loose Edges: Unchecked
Tangent Space: Unchecked

Armatures:
Only Deform Bones: Unchecked
Add Leaf Bones: Checked
Primary Bone Axis: Y Axis
Secondary Bone Axis: X Axis
Armature FBXNode Type: Null

Animation:
Baked Animations: Checked
Key All Bones: Checked
NLA Strips: Checked
All Actions: Checked
Force Start/End Keying: Checked
Sampling Rate: 1.00
Simplify: 1.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Metroid/comments/6dief4/metroid_prime_maps_ripped_models/), you need to detatch the armature from the mesh, and then attach it using with empty groups. I would also recommend using 'L' to import the mesh into the blend file that you're exporting from.

Reddit post:
In order to retain armature and animations, do the following:

Disconnect the model from the armature

Reconnect and select weight by "Empty Groups"

Disable 60fps interpolation on the animations

Make all data local

There are other steps im probably forgetting but these are the most important ones.

Comment: You should probably write/paste the relevant parts of that thread into the answer, in case the Reddit thread/comment goes away, the answer can still be found on SO.

Comment: Why would we need the Reddit post? they don't typically dissapear.